# I can't propose an edit to certain questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, editing

Seemingly at random, I can't propose edits for some questions.

An example is [Third party shore-excursion operators in the Western Caribbean](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/426/3rd-party-shore-excursion-operators-in-the-western-carribean).  I can just see `link - close - flag` below the question.

But I can edit [US Customs Pre-clearance in foreign airports](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/423/us-customs-pre-clearance-in-foreign-airports), even before it got an answer.  I see `link - edit - retag - close - flag` on that question.

It appears to have nothing to do with my score in various tags, unless I'm missing something.

It looks like I *can* propose an edit if I go directly to the edit page -- e.g. `https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/426/edit` for the first question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the timing, it's probable that you couldn't edit a given question because it had an outstanding edit needing approval.